How Much Extra Time to Replace Existing Windows with New Build Windows?
Big box store is offering credit towards installation for providing two new-build windows, instead of ordered replacement windows. (Aluminum 106x59" and 70x34") I'm wondering how many additional hours it should take the contractor to install them? (Store and contractor have vastly different ideas about it.)  

The amount of time it takes usually is more of a matter of experience in doing it.

How much time should it take an experienced contractor to do it?

New build windows are for New construction.  The time to install would be substantially more than if Replacement windows were used.  It sounds like the store wants to sell off slow moving new construction windows. The only way to get actual figures for install is to have a window installation professional come to your house and know what they are expected to install.  I suspect it won't be cheap.

I suspect that what they are selling as replacement windows are insert windows. These install into the existing window opening after the sashes have been removed, and require very little work on the window framing or trim. As a result, they install quickly and easily. The disadvantage is that since you are installing a new window frame within the existing window frame, the glass or ventilation area of the window is reduced.
New build windows install into the raw framing. Replacing an existing window with one of these requires ripping out a lot more of the existing window, and correspondingly more finishing work. But it would retain the full size of your current window.
It's a trade-off. If you are having a contractor do it, I would discuss the work involved and the costs with them; if you don't like their estimate, get a couple more estimates and, usually, discard the lowest and highest. If you are doing it yourself, the relative simplicity of installing insert windows inclines me to suggest you stay with those.
